# some sort of writer

Tags: creative-writing

I'm some sort of writer. if I start writing short paras it is ok. if I start writing poetry I kill it too. I'm a software engineer by profession, but I'm too confused about my passion. What should I do?

Comment: Do 3 things: practice, practice, practice.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm not clear on what you're asking our help with? Could yo [edit] your question to make it clearer? Please note that we are not a forum, but a Q&A site; the questions we can answer are clear questions, which can potentially have one "correct" answer. Questions that are primarily opinion-based are off-topic for us. You can find out more on our [tour], [help] and [ask] pages.

Comment: Were you functioning on the assumption that one should follow whatever their passion is, and now you're uncertain what you're passionate about?  Or are you meaning to assert that you're now passionate about writing, and you want advice as to how to proceed with it?  We would be able to offer you better answers if you clarified your question.

Comment: The question has been placed on hold as unclear for now. Please consider editing this into a clearer question and we'll consider re-opening it.

Comment: I write fiction. I write poetry. I write questions and answers on SE. And I write software. I enjoy all of these. They are all writing. No one can decide on a niche for you though. It's hard. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To be a passionate writer, you need to be a passionate reader.**

Reading across genres and reading levels will expose you to a multitude of writing styles.  When I started out as a writer at the age of about 8, I developed my style by emulating the styles of my favorite authors.  In time, I assimilated mannerisms that I saw and enjoyed and began to experiment with new things, like repetition and figurative language.  **Emulation is not plagiarism, and can help you develop your writing skills.**

Once you have found a style that you like and that works with your writing, you have to seek out criticism.  Peer reviews and writing groups where you have to share your writing can be really nerve-wracking, but getting outside influence will improve both your self-esteem in regards to your writing and your writing itself.  **Knowing whether or not the ideas, themes, and plot lines of your pieces are clear to readers is very important, and only editing by yourself can make you overlook critical mistakes or flaws within your writing.**

Practicing daily and constantly and consistently reaching out to others for constructive criticism will make you a better and more confident writer, and will help you find the genre of writing that you are most passionate about.

Answer (score 2):

Show your writing to someone else to read, to get an idea of what they think.  Join a writing group where you learn about writing.  The teacher can comment on your writing, whether it is a good as you think it is.